# Visual Studio Unable to activate Windows Store app

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I have a problem with UWP and Visual Studio 2015 Pro. I created a Visual C++ UWP app and I just wanna to send requests to a server. This code compiles good, but when Studio starts the application, I get this error:

> Unable to activate Windows Store app 'Package Name'. The App5.exe
>   process started, but the activation request failed with error 'The app
>   didn't start'.

I found this problem on Microsoft's forum and on Stackoverflow too, but this solutions doesn't help me! I tried restore developer mode and license, tried reinstalling Visual Studio (VS 2017 Community has the problem too), tried reinstalling app, and create new project too. Same results.

**But Console Application works good!**

How I can fix this problem? Thanks!

**UPD:**
In Debug/Output i have:

```
'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App1\Debug\App1\AppX\App1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.24210.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\vccorlib140d_app.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.24210.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\msvcp140d_app.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x25bc has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The thread 0x20b8 has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The program '[8128] App1.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.
```

Dependency walker show this errors: https://pp.userapi.com/c824601/v824601273/444bf/awP70BN-phs.jpg

Comment: have you activated developer mode in settings app? Also the app project must be stored on local hard drive not on network drive.

Comment: Yes, i activate developer mode, and my project stored on local hard drive in default VS projects path

Comment: If you use visual studio build and deploy to local machine directly, and start it from "start menu", did it work? Besides, UWP applications have restrictions with access to network. Try to add Internet (Client & Server), Internet (Client) and Private Networks (Client & Server) capabilities in the "Package.appxmanifest".

Comment: can you run other apps?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT , no, it's not work. In output i have
The thread 0x25bc has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The thread 0x20b8 has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The program '[8128] App1.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'. Problem here. Dependency walker shows this errors: https://pp.userapi.com/c824601/v824601273/444bf/awP70BN-phs.jpg

Comment: @magicandre1981, yes, other apps runs ok, if i don't send requests

Comment: @4L3X How long did you send request to server? Which part of your code did you send the request?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT i use Poco library to send requests. I also try use curl, but i have problems too

Comment: @4L3X Please answer my above questions. How long did this request take? Which part of your code did you send the request in? In `OnLaunched`? or other places? Because system doesn't allow you to do a long time task in application’s constructor and OnLaunched(), if you spend a long time to request from network, the system may think your app is unresponsive and terminate it.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Hm, no, not in OnLaunched. I have one page - MainPage, and button "request" in XAML. I sending request in click handler's method - request_click()

Comment: @4L3X If so, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I fixed problem. I just rewrite project on C# :D Thank's!